# Why does the C++ compiler not catch a missing function implementation?

Tags: c++, c++14

I added a bunch of functions to the header file and the implementations to the cpp file.  However, I forgot to add one function definition and the code still compiled.  Why is that?  What would've been the behavior had I not caught this?  Would it just have thrown some runtime exception when I tried to run the code?

Comment: The linker may, if the function is required. Otherwise, depends a lot on link flags and the platformm.

Comment: It is not the **compiler's** job to catch missing implementations, it is the **linker's** job.  And if the missing function is not actually called in code, the compiler *may* decide not to emit a reference to it for the linker to resolve.

Comment: You would've got a compile-time error if you used the function. If you didn't get a error, it means the function was declared but never used.

Comment: If you don't use a function, why does it need to be defined?

Comment: From C++ compiler perspective, not having a function definition for a used function is a violation of ODR (One Definition Rule). The program is malformed, no diagnostics is required. Not having a function definition for a function which is not used is perfectly OK.

Comment: Got it, thanks everyone!  So, to summarize, the compilation would've failed when the client that uses that function is added.  Still a little weird because that code would've been written by someone else later.  Is there some way to force the compiler/linker to catch this case?

Comment: @Pratik If there is, it's compiler dependent. You could ask a separate question about that, asking about a specific compiler.

Comment: It’s a feature. Before you could delete functions it was one way of building a non-copyable idiom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not an error to declare a function in a file and not imlement it -- people do it all the time in header files.

If a function is called and does not exist, it will be caught at link time.

If it's not used, I don't think the declaration will generally create a "reference" for the linker, so will not flag an error.

*EDIT -- additional thought:*
I think there may be a misunderstanding that the compiler expects there to be a one-to-one correspondence between the header file declaring a class and the implementation of the class.  This is a very good practice, but the compiler doesn't care.  It is perfectly fine to the compiler to have the implementation of a particular function of a class be in a third file.  It would be very poor style, unless there was good reason (like the implementation file was getting unreasonably long, or some part needed be split off for a particular platform or something).

But, if someone thought that the compiler looked at the header file and the .cpp file as a matched pair, I definitely see why they would think the compiler should have an error or warning if something declared does not have an implementation.

Comment: Note that it *is* ill-formed to not define a non-pure virtual member function even if it isn't invoked. (But the definition does not need to be in the same TU where the declaration is, so a compiler cannot detect missing definition). Also, standard doesn't require that the linker detects a missing function definition, although it may be quite likely that it does.